# Ui-Router: get name of view in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

With the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) for angularJS you can use multiple views on the same page/state.

Each view contains a template, controller, etc. but it seems like unlike for states there is no way to assign a "resolve" function to a view.

Now i have several similar views which are using the same controller (which means the controller gets instanciated once per view). Obviously I need to pass some information to the controller, depending on which view he is currently managing. Preferably I would do this when the controllers get instanciated. I can not access this information inside the controller via `$state` though since it does not provide informations on the view assigned to the controller..

Since the view is establishing the link between template and controller (and manage its lifecycle via `ui-view`, i was hoping i could pass information to the controller using the view-object. Without a `resolve` function i do not see a way to do this though, so is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $state.$current to get the name of the current state.

Comment: well yes.. but like i said i can not extract any information about the views from the current state (except for the list of all available views on that state).

Comment: Actually I'm a bit perplexed by your 'cant add a resolve to a view', because we do that a lot with our app and have a not small amount of them.

Comment: I tried that and it works (as in "it does not crash"), but apparently the resolve is registered to the parent state instead of the view itself. According to the ui-router documentation: `The resolve keyword MUST be relative to state not views (in case you use multiple views)`